# Create custom UISearchBar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

How would I create a custom search bar that looks like this:
[image: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6EhDUFD0hA0/VbZJ48sqIBI/AAAAAAAAEH4/iV7nZlh9hqk/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-07-27%2Bat%2B8.01.28%2BAM.png]

I could also use a textfield if that would be easier. How would I create a text field that looks like this using Swift?

Comment: Have you considered using UISearchBar from the Object Library (on the bottom of Utilities section)?

Answer (score 1):

Create your customTextField class and inherit it from `UITextField`.

Make its edges round setting cornerRadius for its `layer` and color it gray the same way.

Add a `UIImageView` with on top of the search bar.

Accept touches on the view. On `touchesBegan`, make the textField `becomeFirstResponder` and make the image `hidden` to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a custom textfield or search bar you are going to have to do it programatically. You can add the search bar or textfield to the view but in order to get a customized look, like the one in the picture below. Also, make sure that you have all the code in the **ViewDidLoad()** and create an outlet for the item on the view. It isn't hard to do and I'm sure you will get the desired outcome as long as you are willing to go through some trial and error!

Don't worry doing all the customization is a bunch of fun, and give a great feeling after you have solved it!

I hope this helps